# Is such redirection "|>" just an error or it means something?

Tags: bash, io-redirection

I typed `|>` by mistake but `bash` didn't print any errors. (But it did create an empty file.) For example,

```
date |> tmp.txt
```

I thought maybe it actually means something ?

Comment: Are you sure the command isn’t of the form `date |> tmp.txt cmd2`? Because that changes the answer.

Answer (score 18):

That seems to be just a pipeline where the second part is an empty command, only containing the redirection. Writing it as `date | >file` might make it easier to interpret. The empty command doesn't do anything but process the redirection, creating the file.

`date >| file` on the other hand would act as an override for the `noclobber` shell option, which prevents the regular `>` from overwriting existing files.

```
$ touch foo; set -o noclobber
$ date > foo
bash: foo: cannot overwrite existing file
$ date >| foo       # works
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it will not throw error because for bash `> file` means redirect to a file named `file`. As in your case there is nothing to redirect to file, bash will just create a file name `file` with nothing in it.

```
[bd@centos-6.5 my-tests]$ date | > my_file
[bd@centos-6.5 my-tests]$ cat my_file
[bd@centos-6.5 my-tests]$
```

Comment: Funny. Zsh has a different behavior: after the command, `my_file` contains the output of `date`.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi, in `zsh`, when there are only redirections and no command, `zsh` runs the `$NULLCMD` command (`cat` by default) or `$READNULLCMD` (a pager by default) if there are only _input_ redirections.